# Why does <a> exist, rather than a form submission of method type get?

Tags: html, http, history

I'm simply curious, as to why HTML has an anchor tag used to preform GET requests specifically without ability to change HTTP request type, or otherwise why not use the form submission convention, as we may have the possibility of get-variables anyway.

More interesting is how anchor tags link to #id sections of the same page.

Is there a good reason, or is this simply a dogmatic leftover?

**Edit: I'm not asking about what they do, I'm questioning the convention of anchor tags and form submissions.**

Why isn't it an HTTP request element that covers these bases, and defaults as GET, so it works with a link? Why was this convention decided upon. I'm saying it sounds insane to me and I want to know if there's any justification from when it was decided upon.

Answer (score 1):

An anchor connects two documents or parts of documents, i.e. the current and the referenced. But a form doesn’t. A form is for sending queries. That’s it.

Comment: Then why do we allow GET variables in HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` tag is used to navigate from one page to another, which requires GET requests only. And because URLs support the possibility of sending variables (e.g. `?a=b`) there is absolutely no need for a more complex tag.

Obviously, the `<a>` tag is an inline element, while the `<form>` tag is a block element. So you could conclude that anchor tags need to be *simple*, while form elements may be a bit more complex.

Comment: Right, but the return code and content doesn't depend on on what request method was used. For instance, you can easily get one resource to return two results with different request-methods. The A tag isn't really inline, as you need to define inner-html, which could end up making the thing into a block anyways, regardless of the fact the browser doesn't tie-in any input elements with it. I could just as easily create a hyperling that does `<form method="get" action="example.com"><input type="hidden" name="arg" value="1"><input type="submit">Go there</submit></form>`

Comment: equal to `<a href="example.com?arg=1">click here</a>, but the convention seems really weird

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use **get** because you can perform the entire action with one string and no additional tags. It's short and simple and for most parameter-passing and navigation applications it's perfect.

POST is for forms and file attachments. GET is limited in size, POST is not.

> More interesting is how anchor tags
>   link to #id sections of the same page.
>
> Is there a good reason, or is this
>   simply a dogmatic leftover?

No, hash URLS are still useful and are a good non-javascript fallback for in-page navigation. Hash URLs are now being taken to the next level in order to maintain state and bookmarking of AJAX-based pages.